# How should I test on a small dataset?

Tags: testing, dataset, weka

I use Weka to test machine learning algorithms on my dataset. I have 3800 rows and around 25 features. I am testing the combination of different features for prediction models and seem to predict lower than just the oneR algorithm does with the use of Cross-validation. Even C4.5 does not predict better, sometimes it does and sometimes it does not on basis of the features that are still able to classify.

But, on a certain moment I splitted my dataset in a testset and dataset(20/80), and testing it on the testset, the C4.5 algorithm had a far higher accuracy than my OneR algorithm had. I thought, with the small size of the dataset, it probably is just a coincidence that it predicted very well(the target was still splitted up relatively as target attributes). And therefore, its more useful to use Cross-validation on small datasets like these.

However, testing it on another testset, did give the high accuracy towards the testset using C4.5. So, my question actually is, what is the best way to test datasets when the datasets are actually pretty small?

I saw some posts where it is discussed, but I am still not sure what is the right way to do it.

Comment: cross validated http://stats.stackexchange.com/ seems to be better place for this question

Answer (score 0):

It's almost always a good approach to test your model via Cross-Validation.
A rule of thumb is to use 10 fold cross validation.

In your case, 10 fold cross validation will do the following in Weka:

- split your 3800 training instances into 10 sets of 380 instances
- for each set (s = 1 .. 10) :

  - use the instances from ***s*** for testing and the other 9 sets for training a           model (3420 training instances)
- the result will be an average of the results obtained with the 10 models used.

Try to avoid testing your dataset using the training set option, because that could result in creating a model that works very well for you existing data but could have big problems with other new instances (overfitting).